# @babel/plugin-transform-runtime for react project

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, core-js

I would like to make react application with `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` to support for IE9
If I use `core-js, @babel/polyfill`will pollute the global scope.
Actually another external library (core-js is definded) conflict with my application. Unfortunately I have to include external library (shCore.js)

That is why I want to use `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`
So what should I do to make react application for IE9 with @babel/plugin-transform-runtime

// package.json

```
{
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.8.3",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
"css-loader": "^3.2.1",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
"style-loader": "^1.0.1",
"url-loader": "^3.0.0",
"webpack": "^4.41.5",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.2"
},
"dependencies": {
"@babel/runtime": "^7.8.3",
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"core-js": "^3.6.1",
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-icons": "^3.8.0",
"react-redux": "^7.1.3",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"redux": "^4.0.4",
"redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
}
}
```

// webpac.config.js

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(js)$/,
    exclude: {
      test: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
      exclude: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-dom"),  // <- something like this!!
      ]
    },
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', {'targets': {'browsers': ["ie > 8"]}}],
        ['@babel/preset-react', {'targets': {'browsers': ["ie > 8"]}}]
      ],
      plugins: [
        [
          "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
          "absoluteRuntime": false,
          "corejs": false,            
          "helpers": true,                                  
          "regenerator": true,                         
          "useESModules": true,                             
        }],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", {loose: true}]
      ],
    },
  }
]
```

},

Answer (score 0):

If you directly import core-js or @babel/polyfill and the built-ins it provides such as Promise, Set and Map, those will pollute the global scope. While this might be ok for an app or a command line tool, it becomes a problem if your code is a library which you intend to publish for others to use or if you can't exactly control the environment in which your code will run.

The transformer will alias these built-ins to core-js so you can use them seamlessly without having to require the polyfill.

Reference from [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime#why)